# Not created class table (not seen in Admin)

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I create new model:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=30);
   subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Create migration:

```
E:\Dropbox\djagoBlog\blog>python manage.py migrate --fake account zero
Operations to perform:
  Unapply all migrations: account
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Run migation:

```
python manage.py migrate account
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account
Running migrations:
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
```

Byt in Admin I not see new table Subscribe

What problem?

Comment: You need to add it to the `admin`.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating models is *not* enough to show them in the admin panel. You need to "register" these models.

In the `app` where you defined the models, there is normally an `admin.py` file, where you can register your model(s), like:

```
# app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Subscribe

admin.site.register(Subscribe)
```

In case you want to attach specific behavior to such model admin (for example by adding actions), you can make a `ModelAdmin` class, and specify that behavior, as is specified in the [documentation on `ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).